# Why do I get `$` in prompt instead of `user@hostname:~$` while SSHing into docker container? Am I logged in as user?

Tags: ssh, users, docker

I am trying to ssh into my Ubuntu docker container. But when I try, it's not entering as my user, but instead into some DOS terminal.

[image: terminal when I ssh into container]

But when I use `bash` command, it will give me a bash terminal with my user as usual.

[image: After giving bash command]

Following is my Dockerfile for Ubuntu container

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y install awscli --upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "remote_user:password" | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh -p && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/sshdh   
COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown remote_user:remote_user   -R /home/remote_user && \
    chmod 400 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN ssh-keygen -A
EXPOSE 22
RUN rm -rf /run/nologin
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

How can I ssh into my container as a user(here remote_user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you SSH into your box, a shell is spawned. Which shell this is, is defined in the file `/etc/passwd` in your Docker image. I suspect it lists `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`.

Your Dockerfile lists a command to create a new user in your image. This command is `useradd`, and that's the command that will alter `/etc/passwd` inside your Docker image. Try to use `useradd --shell /bin/bash remote_user` instead of `useradd remote_user`. Then rebuild your Docker image, and create a new container from that image.

Comment: That was a crystal clear answer. It worked, thanks!. And sorry for not voting up for your answer! I don't have enough reputation for it. XD.